# Displaying list items at different widths based on number of items

Tags: html, css

My CSS needs to be modified to show 5 items, but if items are less than 5, it should cover the width.

```css
/* new css added */

.product-section {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 108px 80px 0;
}

.product-section h6 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #585253;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  padding: 0 0 6px;
}

.veiwed-related {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 66px 0 0;
}

.recently-veiwed-related ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -33px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.veiwed-related ul li {
  width: 16.5%;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 20px 33px;
  padding: 0;
}

.veiwed {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}


/* new css added */
```

```html
<div class="product-section">
  <h6>you may also like</h6>
  <div class="veiwed-related">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that if there are 5 `<li>`s, it comes under that width, but if i have only 1 or 3, it covers the width?

Comment: you need a javascript, that will count the list then divide the width ex. 100/5 list then 20 the width will be 20%;

Answer (score 0):

I think in `view-related` you want to do that so for that:

```
.veiwed-related ul li{
max-width:16.5%; //adjust the width by using max width so that it do not take unwanted place
float:left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 20px 33px;
padding: 0;
}
```

`max-width` will give a limit to your width and If there will be less items the size will be automatically decreased because you are specifying it maximum value not the fixed value

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could pull something like that out is with JavaScript though since CSS doesn't have conditionals to begin with.

```
// JS
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".product-section ul li");
if (items.length < 5)
{
   items.forEach(function (item) {
     item.style.width = (100 / items.length).toFixed(2) + "%";
   });
}
```

an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4xe7dwxp/)

hope that helps

Comment: it works, but the condition seems false which u added, < 5, i used >= 5 and it shows 5, also i see the class u added create very big images inside that li tags

Comment: For odd reason I misundertood your question, what you wanted was to make all items to fill the width of the container in a single row, I thought it was to make the item `100%`. Updated my answer for your needs

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you need to use javascript to identify the number of `<li>`s, then you can use it to:

- Define the new width of `<li>`s

or

- Create a class on your `<ul>` then use CSS to control the width of
  `<li>`s (.items-5, .items-4, .items-3)